# "Design and system-related aspects" on a project?

Tags: job-search, resume

I'm filling out a job application (full stack dev), and one of the questions is to describe some design and system related aspects on a project I worked on "that I had to consider", followed by a very small textbox.

What the hell do I put in here? It's way too short to describe an entire project I worked on, and I don't know how do I sum it up in a sentence or two. Also, what even qualifies as "design and system-related, that I had to consider", it sounds quite non-specific?

Comment: You can briefly summarize the project, and your role, contribution to the project, and the tech stack that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s looking for “aspects you had to consider”, so they’re not looking for anything in-depth at this stage.

It can be a pain to mind-read what’s needed here, so a few aspects of the relevant technology/platforms should demonstrate that you understand the technical parts of the work and hopefully lead the interviewer toward asking you for more details in the interview stage.

There’s nothing wrong in simply being straightforward and pointing out that you’ll be happy to discuss this question in person (if the rest of the application demonstrates enough skill/experience)

It wouldn’t be the first time that the design of an application form doesn’t match what’s needed.